# The "Letter U" Rebus

Tags: visual, rebus

Here is a rebus I thought of again. Can you solve it?

[image: Rebus2]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could be:

> NOT FOR US; multiple Us

OR

> NOT FOR USE; another use of Us

Comment: 2nd answer, okay.

Answer (score 7):

Is it

> Not for use under 6?
>  As would be printed on a medicine bottle

EDIT:

> Not for use?

Comment: Almost... now you need to remove 2 words...

Comment: If this is the intended answer, then @u_ndefined I don't see what's the use of anything other than the last line.

Comment: So, people don't like the answer, but not sure why *I'm* getting the downvotes

Answer (score 3):

Is it:

> Not for you. (NOT 4 U).

Comment: Hello, you are very close to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

May be:

> One to you, three not for you

Comment: Hello, sorry, there are no parts, but your answer is very close.

Comment: Your previous answer is already close.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is:

> Not for internal use

Because

> If we call the bottom row "four internal u's", the red mark makes it "not four internal u's", which sounds like the above phrase.
> This is also a very common warning printed on product packaging.

Edit:

> I am convinced that the solution contains something similar to the phrase "Not for use in/under (blank)."

Comment: Hello, your answer is incorrect, but good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> There is naught for you at the bottom of the pyramid.

Comment: Not the answer I had, sorry.